# Watermarked Textbox for Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework

Does anyone know if anyone makes a watermarked textbox control for the compact framework?

I already loked at the following and didn't see one.

[Component One Mobile](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioMobile/)

[Pocket PC Controls](http://www.pocketpccontrols.com/)

[Resco Mobile Forms Toolkit](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daniel Moth has a pretty good blog post about how to do this here:

[TextBox with cue banner support for Windows Mobile](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2006/07/textbox-with-cue-banner-support-for.html)

Best of all it is simple and free!

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen one.  [This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WaterMark.aspx) shows how to do it yourself - not sure if it would work on CF, but I didn't see any obvious non-CF supported stuff in the example.